# ncks error when variable name has spaces

Tags: python, nco, ncks

```
ncks -v name of var inp.nc out.nc
```

I have a netCDF file with a hyperslab called `name of var` However, since the hyperslab has a space in the name, it leads to an error"

`ncks: ERROR recieved 3 filenames; need no more than two`

How to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried putting `name of var` inside quotes? or escaping the spaces with backslashes? For example `name\ of\ var`?

Comment: I had tried `'...'` and that  did not work, but `"..."` do work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elethan is right. Quoting the variable is the simplest solution. Both of these will work:

```
ncks -v "name of var" in.nc out.nc
ncks -v 'name of var' in.nc out.nc
```